# Can we move an icon to the right edge of the taskbar?

Tags: taskbar, shortcuts, icons

I have created a shortcut to shutdown the computer and have placed it on the taskbar. Up to now I haven't spoiled anything by accidentally clicking it.
My question is, can we place that icon on the right end (of course before the date & time and the other icons like sound and network) of the taskbar so that I am much forgiven about accidentally shutting down the PC?

Comment: If you're using Windows, I don't think you can, but you can create it on the desktop just above there. You may wish to add a prompt for confirmation, maybe with a time-out of a few seconds.

Comment: What you are asking for isn't exactly possible but a very similar effect can be achieved by putting a launcher for your app in the task tray (instead of the task bar). Just Google for something like 'any program tasktray'. After you install one of those apps you'll just need to create a launcher for it.

Comment: An even better answer would be to just ignore the icon and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> over and over until you get the Windows Shutdown dialog.